# Edge bug - list items don't paint with correct css due to Materialize JS files. But do after toggling in inspector

Tags: javascript, materialize, microsoft-edge

I've made a video showing this in action (Edge runs slow, but you'll see)
https://youtu.be/jZr12MKQRow

The menu is painted on and doesn't properly render the correct CSS for some reason, especially regarding list-style and line-height. Toggling either of those two attributes within Edge inspector makes it appear correctly.

In order to debug this, I modified my Grunt file and narrowed it down to 1 of 5 files that is doing this. Here they are in Grunt.

```
'node_modules/materialize-css/js/hammer.min.js',
'node_modules/materialize-css/js/jquery.hammer.js'
'node_modules/materialize-css/js/collapsible.js',
'node_modules/materialize-css/js/parallax.js',
'node_modules/materialize-css/js/sideNav.js',
```

And here is the compiled JS: https://pastebin.com/gncKzVb2

Here is the HTML markup

```html
<ul id="desktop-categories" class="hidden-xs">
    <li class="category-nav">
      <a href="#" class="parent">Shop by Category</a>

      <ul class="uprod-cats">
        <li class="back-link"><a href="#" class="parent" data-action="pop-menu" name=
        "back-sidebar" id="back-sidebar"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>
        Back</a></li>

        <li>
          <a class="parent" href="#">Automotive</a>

          <ul class="third-level two-col">
            <li class="back-link"><a href="#" class="parent" data-action="pop-menu" name=
            "back-sidebar" id="back-sidebar"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>
            Back</a></li>

            <li>
              <a class="parent" href="#">Exterior</a>

              <ul>
                <li class="back-link"><a href="#" class="parent" data-action="pop-menu"
                name="back-sidebar" id="back-sidebar"><i class=
                "material-icons">chevron_left</i> Back</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a class="parent" href="#">Interior</a>

              <ul>
                <li class="back-link"><a href="#" class="parent" data-action="pop-menu"
                name="back-sidebar" id="back-sidebar"><i class=
                "material-icons">chevron_left</i> Back</a></li>

                <li><a href="/taxons/automotive/interior/vinyl">Vinyl</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a class="parent" href="#">Marine</a>

          <ul class="third-level">
            <li class="back-link"><a href="#" class="parent" data-action="pop-menu" name=
            "back-sidebar" id="back-sidebar"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>
            Back</a></li>

            <li><a href="/taxons/marine/vinyl">Vinyl</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a class="parent" href="#">Outdoor</a>

          <ul class="third-level">
            <li class="back-link"><a href="#" class="parent" data-action="pop-menu" name=
            "back-sidebar" id="back-sidebar"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>
            Back</a></li>

            <li><a href="/taxons/outdoor/vinyl">Vinyl</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a class="parent" href="#">Upholstery Tools</a>

          <ul class="third-level">
            <li class="back-link"><a href="#" class="parent" data-action="pop-menu" name=
            "back-sidebar" id="back-sidebar"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>
            Back</a></li>

            <li><a href="/taxons/upholstery-tools/cutting-tools">Cutting Tools</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a class="parent" href="#">Upholstery Supplies</a>

          <ul class="third-level">
            <li class="back-link"><a href="#" class="parent" data-action="pop-menu" name=
            "back-sidebar" id="back-sidebar"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>
            Back</a></li>

            <li><a href="/taxons/upholstery-supplies/thread">Thread</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/taxons/closeouts">Closeouts</a></li>

        <li><a href="/taxons/specials">Specials</a></li>

        <li><a href="/taxons/contract">Contract</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

If I remove any of those 5 files, the menu won't even open in Edge, so this is as far as my knowledge can take me.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey, can you provide the HTML of the navigation as well? Looking at the video it seems to be an invalidation issue - which essentially means that the JS dirtied styles in some way that the engine missed and thus didn't update styles, you clicking the `line-height` forced this recalc and thus the rendering looks correct. That said, I can't be sure without a repro (the js above isn't enough).

Comment: @gregwhitworth I added the surrounding markup. I stripped out a few menu items but left all of the meat of it. Thank you

Comment: Ok, so when I combine the JS with the HTML - things aren't working as your repro, so there must be some CSS missing or hookup code that you've left out. You can see my try at getting a running repro here: http://jsbin.com/ducigaqado/edit?html,js,console,output if you want - can you get that running and then save a snapshot. If it would be easier I can try to reduce the issue for you - just file the bug at bugs.microsoftedge.com and reply here with the bug ID. You can make the bug private if you don't want the URL to be public.